# Binary Floating point to decimal JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, floating-point, binary

To answer the original question that was closed due to an invalid moderation.
[Binary Floating point to decimal JavaScript fucntion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69499984/binary-floating-point-to-decimal-javascript-fucntion#)

This function below basically does the math based on the floating point logic.

Does anyone know of a built in function in JavaScript to do this? or a more straight forward way?

```js
function fp32BinToDec(inputFpBinDiv) {
  var inputFpBin = document.getElementById(inputFpBinDiv).value;

  var expBin = inputFpBin.substring(1, 9);
  var mantBin = inputFpBin.substring(9, 33);

  var expDec = (parseInt(expBin, 2) - 127);

  var mantDec = (parseInt(mantBin, 2) / (2 ** 23));

  var dec = ((1 + mantDec) * (2 ** (expDec)));

  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = dec;
  console.log(dec);
  return dec;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Floating point Binary to Decimal</title>
  <script src="site.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="fp32BinToDec('inputField')">Convert to Decimal</button><br>
  <input id="inputField" value="01000100100110011010000000000000"></input><br>
  <p>Output: </p>
  <div id="output"></div><br>
  <p>Default Floating point binary should result a decimal of 1129</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There's nothing like this is the language. I thought maybe one of the cool math libraries like [math.js](https://mathjs.org) might have it, but I'm not seeing anything. If you don't mind, I'm curious about a couple of things: how your code accounts for the sign, and whether you use other languages that have this built in (like Mathematica, maybe?)

Comment: Answering your own question is ok, but it is preferred that you ask a question then post a separate answer than can be voted on and accepted.